# After Spartacus upgrade from v1.5.5 to v2.1.6 shows error "Cannot read property 'getActive' of undefined"

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have updated my storefront from v1.5.5 to v2.1.6.
It shows below error,
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getActive' of undefined
at spartacus-core.js:12517**

[check here for console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6MFE.png)

Help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

did you follow the upgrade instructions?

Comment: Thanks @Erik.
I followed instructions from below docs, but not working.

https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/updating-to-version-2/

https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=8.2-9.1